# VSTO Custom Ribbon Not Showing

Tags: .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019#DesigningRibbonLayout

But no matter what I do my custom tab just doesn't show up. Here's a list of things I've tried:

- Checking that the addin is enabled
- Ending orphan processes
- Restarting Outlook
- Rebooting my PC
- Adding a button to the default Addin tab (This did not show either)

Anyone got any ideas?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 with target .NET framework 4.7.2, and trying to make an addin for Outlook 365 if that helps

Answer (score 8):

Ok so I've figured it out. For anyone else running into this problem you need to change the RibbonType property to "Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer". I was stuck because I couldn't find the property - to make it appear, click on the white space above or around the tab and not the tab itself.